# Which is more resource intensive for the same kind of work: (phantomjs + selenium) or (phantomjs + casperjs)?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, browser, phantomjs, casperjs

If same work has to be accomplished, which combination will yield the result with lesser resource consumption?

`PhantomJS + Selenium` or

`PhantomJS + CasperJS`?

Comment: You would have to specify which selenium runtime. The JVM is quite memory intensive. What resources did you have in mind? Can you provide a scenario what each of them should do? A simple `driver.get` or `casper.start` doesn't show anything. Do you want a metric how they behave for a long script (hint: memory leak)? Please take your time to answer every remark by editing your question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm very new to browser automation. I've not used Selenium. I didn't know which browsers selenium supported and didn't want to spend resources with a fully stacked browser in the background. I came to know about casperjs which uses phantomjs and I have been trying to use it for my current project. At the moment I am stuck at handling the `XHR` responses in casperjs. I looked at the docs but couldn't find a proper sublink. Can you please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555370/how-can-catch-and-process-the-data-from-the-xhr-responses-using-casperjs