# How can I catch and process the data from the XHR responses using casperjs?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

The data on the webpage is displayed dynamically and it seems that checking for every change in the html and extracting the data is a very daunting task and also needs me to use very unreliable XPaths. So I would want to be able to extract the data from the `XHR` packets.

I hope to be able to extract information from `XHR` packets as well as generate 'XHR' packets to be sent to the server. 
The extracting information part is more important for me because the sending of information can be handled easily by automatically triggering html elements using casperjs.

I'm attaching a screenshot of what I mean.[image]

The text in the response tab is the data I need to process afterwards. (This XHR response has been received from the server.)

Comment: @ArtjomB. For now I just extracted the information from the html elements and deployed the script. Getting the value of the responses would be more elegant though. I will look at using this in a few days time. I'm really sorry, I couldn't incorporate this yet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not easily possible, because the [`resource.received`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-received) event handler only provides meta data like `url`, `headers` or `status`, but not the actual data. The underlying phantomjs event handler acts the same way.

---

## Stateless AJAX Request

If the ajax call **is stateless**, you may repeat the request

```js
casper.on("resource.received", function(resource){
    // somehow identify this request, here: if it contains ".json"
    // it also also only does something when the stage is "end" otherwise this would be executed two times
    if (resource.url.indexOf(".json") != -1 && resource.stage == "end") {
        var data = casper.evaluate(function(url){
            // synchronous GET request
            return __utils__.sendAJAX(url, "GET");
        }, resource.url);
        // do something with data, you might need to JSON.parse(data)
    }
});
casper.start(url); // your script
```

You may want to add the event listener to [`resource.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-requested). That way you don't need to way for the call to complete.

You can also do this right inside of the control flow like this (source: [A: CasperJS waitForResource: how to get the resource i've waited for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560520/1816580)):

```js
casper.start(url);

var res, resData;
casper.waitForResource(function check(resource){
    res = resource;
    return resource.url.indexOf(".json") != -1;
}, function then(){
    resData = casper.evaluate(function(url){
        // synchronous GET request
        return __utils__.sendAJAX(url, "GET");
    }, res.url);
    // do something with the data here or in a later step
});

casper.run();
```

---

## Stateful AJAX Request

If it **is not stateless**, you would need to replace the implementation of XMLHttpRequest. You will need to inject your own implementation of the `onreadystatechange` handler, collect the information in the page `window` object and later collect it in another `evaluate` call.

You may want to look at the [XHR faker in sinon.js](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/blob/master/lib/sinon/util/fake_xml_http_request.js) or use the following complete proxy for `XMLHttpRequest` (I modeled it after method 3 from [How can I create a XMLHttpRequest wrapper/proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4809342/1816580)):

```
function replaceXHR(){
    (function(window, debug){
        function args(a){
            var s = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                s += "\t\n[" + i + "] => " + a[i];
            }
            return s;
        }
        var _XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;

        window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
            this.xhr = new _XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        // proxy ALL methods/properties
        var methods = [ 
            "open", 
            "abort", 
            "setRequestHeader", 
            "send", 
            "addEventListener", 
            "removeEventListener", 
            "getResponseHeader", 
            "getAllResponseHeaders", 
            "dispatchEvent", 
            "overrideMimeType"
        ];
        methods.forEach(function(method){
            window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype[method] = function() {
                if (debug) console.log("ARGUMENTS", method, args(arguments));
                if (method == "open") {
                    this._url = arguments[1];
                }
                return this.xhr[method].apply(this.xhr, arguments);
            }
        });

        // proxy change event handler
        Object.defineProperty(window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype, "onreadystatechange", {
            get: function(){
                // this will probably never called
                return this.xhr.onreadystatechange;
            },
            set: function(onreadystatechange){
                var that = this.xhr;
                var realThis = this;
                that.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    // request is fully loaded
                    if (that.readyState == 4) {
                        if (debug) console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED:", typeof that.responseText == "string" ? that.responseText.length : "none");
                        // there is a response and filter execution based on url
                        if (that.responseText && realThis._url.indexOf("whatever") != -1) {
                            window.myAwesomeResponse = that.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    onreadystatechange.call(that);
                };
            }
        });

        var otherscalars = [
            "onabort",
            "onerror",
            "onload",
            "onloadstart",
            "onloadend",
            "onprogress",
            "readyState",
            "responseText",
            "responseType",
            "responseXML",
            "status",
            "statusText",
            "upload",
            "withCredentials",
            "DONE",
            "UNSENT",
            "HEADERS_RECEIVED",
            "LOADING",
            "OPENED"
        ];
        otherscalars.forEach(function(scalar){
            Object.defineProperty(window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype, scalar, {
                get: function(){
                    return this.xhr[scalar];
                },
                set: function(obj){
                    this.xhr[scalar] = obj;
                }
            });
        });
    })(window, false);
}
```

If you want to capture the AJAX calls from the very beginning, you need to add this to one of the first event handlers

```
casper.on("page.initialized", function(resource){
    this.evaluate(replaceXHR);
});
```

or `evaluate(replaceXHR)` when you need it.

The control flow would look like this:

```
function replaceXHR(){ /* from above*/ }

casper.start(yourUrl, function(){
    this.evaluate(replaceXHR);
});

function getAwesomeResponse(){
    return this.evaluate(function(){
        return window.myAwesomeResponse;
    });
}

// stops waiting if window.myAwesomeResponse is something that evaluates to true
casper.waitFor(getAwesomeResponse, function then(){
    var data = JSON.parse(getAwesomeResponse());
    // Do something with data
});

casper.run();
```

As described above, I create a proxy for XMLHttpRequest so that every time it is used on the page, I can do something with it. The page that you scrape uses the `xhr.onreadystatechange` callback to receive data. The proxying is done by defining a specific setter function which writes the received data to `window.myAwesomeResponse` in the page context. The only thing you need to do is retrieving this text.

---

## JSONP Request

Writing a proxy for JSONP is even easier, if you know the prefix (the function to call with the loaded JSON e.g. `insert({"data":["Some", "JSON", "here"],"id":"asdasda")`). You can overwrite `insert` in the page context

1. after the page is loaded

   ```
   casper.start(url).then(function(){
       this.evaluate(function(){
           var oldInsert = insert;
           insert = function(json){
               window.myAwesomeResponse = json;
               oldInsert.apply(window, arguments);
           };
       });
   }).waitFor(getAwesomeResponse, function then(){
       var data = JSON.parse(getAwesomeResponse());
       // Do something with data
   }).run();
   ```
2. or before the request is received (if the function is registered just before the request is invoked)

   ```
   casper.on("resource.requested", function(resource){
       // filter on the correct call
       if (resource.url.indexOf(".jsonp") != -1) {
           this.evaluate(function(){
               var oldInsert = insert;
               insert = function(json){
                   window.myAwesomeResponse = json;
                   oldInsert.apply(window, arguments);
               };
           });
       }
   }).run();

   casper.start(url).waitFor(getAwesomeResponse, function then(){
       var data = JSON.parse(getAwesomeResponse());
       // Do something with data
   }).run();
   ```

Comment: if i want to fetch image src from website which use ajax to load it , i try the "scrollTo" and "viewport ", but i fails in the end , how should i do ?

Comment: @qianjiahao You should ask a new question and describe your problem properly. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in late 2019, I composed another answer base on this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168312/1265306

Answer (score 7):

I may be late into the party, but the answer may help someone like me who would fall into this problem later in future.

I had to start with PhantomJS, then moved to CasperJS but finally settled with SlimerJS. Slimer is based on Phantom, is compatible with Casper, and can send you back the response body using the same onResponseReceived method, in "response.body" part.

Reference: https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/webpage.html#webpage-onresourcereceived

Comment: But unfortunately, SlimerJS has a dependency on Firefox being installed.

Comment: @nchaud - it's a plus not a minus the way I see it. FF is the strongest browser, with the best support for javascript/DOM

Comment: @nchaud FF or any other XUL Runner, I suppose.

Comment: But it needs to be *installed*, which is the problem if you're developing something that needs to be deployed on, say, client sites. (Understandably this is most heavily used for in-house testing and in that case it's easy enough to install FF/XULRunner on the CI server).

Comment: @nchaud I actually cannot imagine of a situation where you can install SlimerJS but not FF or XULRunner. I think you'd need a installed version of SlimerJS binary somewhere, why can't you have FF installed there as well?

Comment: @openrijal - SlimerJS has a dependency on a browser being installed (FF). PhantomJS has no such dependency - it's a standalone exe. Hence PhantomJS wins in the earlier scenario I mentioned.

Comment: @nchaud in my defense, I think that is an advantage of using Gecko over Webkit. Try to take full page screenshot of https://angular.io with PhantomJS and shoot be back with results, you'll understand.

Comment: Fortunately I don't need to take screenshots in any of my use-cases :)

Answer (score 3):

[@Artjom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561614/1265306)'s doesn't work for me in the recent Chrome and CasperJS versions.

Based on [@Artjom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561614/1265306) and based on [gilly3's answer on how to replace XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987619/1265306), I have composed a new solution that should work in most/all versions of the different browsers. Works for me.

SlimerJS cannot work on newer version of FireFox, therefore no good for me.

Here is the the generic code to add a listner to load of XHR (not dependent on CasperJS):

```
var addXHRListener = function (XHROnStateChange) {

    var XHROnLoad = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            XHROnStateChange(this)
        }
    }

    var open_original = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, unk1, unk2) {
        this.requestUrl = url
        open_original.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    var xhrSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {

        var xhr = this;
        if (xhr.addEventListener) {
            xhr.removeEventListener("readystatechange", XHROnLoad);
            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", XHROnLoad, false);
        } else {
            function readyStateChange() {
                if (handler) {
                    if (handler.handleEvent) {
                        handler.handleEvent.apply(xhr, arguments);
                    } else {
                        handler.apply(xhr, arguments);
                    }
                }
                XHROnLoad.apply(xhr, arguments);
                setReadyStateChange();
            }

            function setReadyStateChange() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (xhr.onreadystatechange != readyStateChange) {
                        handler = xhr.onreadystatechange;
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = readyStateChange;
                    }
                }, 1);
            }

            var handler;
            setReadyStateChange();
        }
        xhrSend.apply(xhr, arguments);
    };

}
```

Here is CasperJS code to emit a custom event on load of XHR:

```
casper.on("page.initialized", function (resource) {
    var emitXHRLoad = function (xhr) {
        window.callPhantom({eventName: 'xhr.load', eventData: xhr})
    }
    this.evaluate(addXHRListener, emitXHRLoad);
});

casper.on('remote.callback', function (data) {
    casper.emit(data.eventName, data.eventData)
});
```

Here is a code to listen to "xhr.load" event and get the XHR response body:

```
casper.on('xhr.load', function (xhr) {
    console.log('xhr load', xhr.requestUrl)
    console.log('xhr load', xhr.responseText)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, you can also directly download the content and manipulate it later. 
Here is the example of the script I am using to retrieve a JSON and save it locally :

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        webSecurityEnabled: false
    }
});

var url = 'https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=whatever';

casper.start('about:blank', function() {
   this.download(url, "hop.json");
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```