# How to access request body in "onResourceRequested" callback in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I would like to access the request body of `HTTP POST` requests in the callback registered with `onResourceRequested` (I didn't find it in the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html)).

I would like to do something like this:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
  var body = networkRequest.body // how to do that ?
  console.log(body)
}
```

How can I access the body of the request in the  `onResourceRequested` callback ?

Comment: That's not directly possible

Comment: Is it an Ajax request? If so, then [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24561614/1816580) should give you some workarounds (PhantomJS and CasperJS are functionally equivalent in this case).

Comment: Yes, it is an `Ajax` request. Thank you for pointing me out at the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The request body of POST requests are stored in the `postData` attribute of `requestData` object. You can retrieve it like so:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
  var body = networkRequest.postData
  console.log(body)
}
```

To note, there doesn't seem to currently be a way to retrieve the request body for any other request methods such as PUT or PATCH.