# How to get the ajax respose data using phantomjs

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am new to phantomjs. I need to get the data from an external site that will loaded through ajax calls that is when I try to load the external site the data will first load in json format in the ajax response then it will be parsed and then loading in the form of tables(i dont know how this will done because it is external website ) now my task is to get the json data which will be load through ajax.This json data I can see from the firebug in firefox then when i click the **open response in a new tab** then another tab will open and I will get the json data. Then I will copy the response url and use in phantomjs then i will get the data but the data i am getting from the response url is different when the data in the external website changes and again i need get the response url and replace it with the previous url I think this is wrong process i am doing .Even I tried of using the location by **copy location** in the firefox and tried to use that but it is showing nothing.  Is there any way that I can load data with out updating every time.

Comment: *"Is there any way that I can load data with out updating every time."* - Probably, but you would have to analyze the site you're dealing with. Open the developer tools (or firebug) in Firefox and see which requests are being made and how they are triggered. Then open the PhantomJS documentation to look for methods (events) to get the same information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I catch and process the data from the XHR responses using casperjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555370/how-can-i-catch-and-process-the-data-from-the-xhr-responses-using-casperjs)