# Fetch API and CasperJS

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, fetch-api

I am trying to do something very similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555370/how-can-i-catch-and-process-the-data-from-the-xhr-responses-using-casperjs), except that instead of XHR, the web app (written in React) uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to do its asynchronous calls.

Is there an elegant way to intercept/overwrite fetch? Basically I want to see each AJAX call the site is doing and grab the data from there. I could just grab it as shown on the site after the fact, but we all know that JSON is easier than HTML to deal with. The site is STATEFUL, so I cannot just resend the URL.

I tried just writing a wrapper like:

```
function replaceFetch(){
    (function(window, debug){
        var _fetch = window.fetch;

        window.fetch = function(u, o = {}) {
            console.log("This is a test");
            return _fetch(u, o);
        }

    })(window, false);
};

casper.on("page.initialized", function(resource){
    this.evaluate(replaceFetch);
});
```

But I get "Untitled suite" error, and can't find anything I can require() to implement Fetch.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: `window.fetch()` only has two functions AFAICS, so it should be even easier to proxy than XMLHttpRequest.